# Ms graph SDK: InternalServerError-Failed to execute request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get all tabs added for a channel
But I am seeing Error.

```
  var tabs = await graphServiceClient.Teams[team.Id].Channels[chanel.Id].Tabs.Request().GetAsync();
```

**Error**

```
{Status Code: InternalServerError
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InternalServerError
Message: Failed to execute request.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 005d47b1-e52e-4ea6-96d4-d0dfb6cfafa7
    date: 2020-02-03T08:14:32
ClientRequestId: 005d47b1-e52e-4ea6-96d4-d0dfb6cfafa7

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.ChannelTabsCollectionRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at S27.Application.Services.MSGraphAPIService.GetTabs(TeamSettingModel team, TeamsChannelModel chanel, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
```

And help?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing one by one each tab in your channel and try to execute your code again. 
In my case there was a Website Tab with some issue. That tab was added via API and the server returned an error despite the tab was added.

Not a good error message and a very bad API behaviour anyway..